# Firefox appears blank when triggered by Behat

Tags: php, selenium, firefox, behat

I want to test several features about an existing website, and even though I'm starting to get used to Behat and its environment, I'm still stuck on some basic things, such as using a web browser to test the javascript on a few pages.

I'm using a Behat "project" for my test, meaning I created a `composer.json` file, ran `composer install` then `bin/behat --init`, and started to create my feature files.

I included selenium2 in my composer dependencies and a `@javascript` tag at the top of a scenario, downloaded a standalone selenium server file, but when Firefox gets triggered, all I get is a white page.

If I understand well, this problem might be because my configuration gets overriden, or because Firefox 57+ isn't well supported.

I have no clue if this is the case, so here are my different files:

**behat.yml**

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  gherkin:
     cache: ~
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://www.spheria.rec
      goutte: ~
      selenium2:
        wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
```

**5-feature-actualite.feature**

```
Feature: Gestion globale des actualités

   Scenario: Arrivée sur le site, connexion et vérification de bonne connexion
        Given I am an anonymous user
        And I go to "/"
        And I should see "Se connecter"
        And I should see "Nom d'utilisateur"
        And I should see "Mot de passe"
        When I fill in "admin@spheria.com" for "name"
        And I fill in "admin" for "pass"
        And I press "Se connecter"
        Then I should get a 200 HTTP response
        And the url should match "/dashboard"
        And I should see "Tableau de bord"

    @javascript
    Scenario: Liste globale des actualités
          Given I am on "/"
          And I fill in "admin@spheria.com" for "name"
          And I fill in "admin" for "pass"
          And I press "Se connecter"
          Then I should get a 200 HTTP response
          And the url should match "/dashboard"
          When I go to "/view/actualite"
          Then I should get a 200 HTTP response
          And I should see "Liste Actualités"
```

**FeatureContext.php**

```
/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends RawDrupalContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext {

  /**
   * FeatureContext constructor.
   * Initializes context.
   *
   * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
   * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
   * context constructor through behat.yml.
   */
  public function __construct() {

  }

  // Here are my custom functions

}
```

Nevertheless, when browsing the seleniumhq issues, I can see that people manage to get their firefox 58 to work. I guess that somehow it should work, but the tons of documentation I read was about writing the test directly with PHP, which is useless to me since I use Behat/Gherkin.

I also tried to use gecko, but no luck so far.

**Edit**
This is the command I use to launch selenium, geckodriver is the root folder

```
java -DWebdriver.gecko.driver="geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium.jar
```

[This is the link to Selenium's trace](https://gist.github.com/Drillan767/62638f14c764182a6e4a561e418cb1ed), since it's way too huge to put here.

And this is the trace from Behat:

> @javascript   Scenario: Liste globale des actualités
>
> Given I am on "/"
>
> Could not open connection: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
>
> Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
>
> System info: host: '64006A38B5DE', ip: '192.168.33.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

What am I missing? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should add the stack-trace error if you have any. Have you started selenium server with `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=path_to_firefox_driver` ?

Comment: I updated my question, added both the stack traces and the command I run for Selenium

Comment: Meanwhile try Chrome.